# How do you set Incemental to true for multiple tables with the same owner using DBMS_STATS.set_table_prefs?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-partitioning

I have around 40-50 tables in my oracle database that are partitioned. Using  DBMS_STATS.set_table_prefs, I want to set "Incremental" to true for all of my partitioned tables. Can anyone help me with this?

Below is the query:

SELECT DISTINCT (table_name), partitioning_type, subpartitioning_type, OWNER
FROM all_part_tables
WHERE OWNER = 'user'
ORDER BY table_name ASC ;

Answer (score 2):

This PL/SQL block (which is based on your comment in another question) loops through partitioned tables for a user and sets their incremental preference to true.

```
begin
    for a in
    (
        select distinct (table_name), owner
        from all_part_tables
        where owner = 'SOME_USER_NAME'
            --Ignore objects in the recycle bin.
            --There are other "tables" that may need to be ignored, 
            --such as external tables, storage tables, etc.
            and table_name not like 'BIN$%'
        order by table_name
    ) loop
        dbms_stats.set_table_prefs(a.owner, a.table_name, 'incremental', 'true');
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: ORA-20001: BIN$Y7E8WBOCISRGU4CK/APUPA==$0 is an invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 45404
ORA-06512: at line 9

Comment: @user9766188 I changed the script to ignore tables in the recycle bin.

Comment: @user9766188 I just noticed that the other question is going down the same path.  You should delete one of these questions so we don't keep duplicating our efforts.